# How to restore the sharepoint list data after deploying project solution again?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, custom-lists, deploying

I have an Visual Studio 2010 empty sharepoint solution project. Solutions consist of several custom lists and workflows attached to that lists. The solution always changes, so it means I'm redeploying the solution very often. After deploying it deletes all of the content from the existed lists and recreates that lists again. Now I'm considering the ways how to solve the problem of disappearing of the data, are there effective ways?

p.s. I cannot use lists created in UI, because I need custom defined lists.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent visual studio from deleting and creating lists, it is by design to ease development. 
During my SharePoint development I've found some workarounds:

1) Put all list instance artifacts in separate project and do not redeploy this project. You can have other project with web parts, workflows etc which you can redeploy.

2) If you change only code and not any SharePoint artifacts then you can use some useful features of [wspbuilder exteinsions](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/releases/view/30858) - it adds custom "WSP builder" option to "Tools" menu. It allows you to deploy your assemblies to GAC without redeploying wsp packages and restart IIS and Timer Service.